# How to get total number of misfiers by quartz scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Is there any method provided by quartz to get **total number of misfiers**, I am aware about a way, with the help of listeners we can identify the misfier occured by the job, but it would be helpful if I can get total misfier count by all the jobs.

I gone throgh the quartz documentation, but didn't find any solution for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz scheduler API does not provide any method that returns the total number of misfires since its restart. You will need to implement a [TriggerListener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/TriggerListener.html) and implement its `triggerMisfired` method and do the counting.

Alternatively, you can use [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com) (I am biased here) or some other Quartz GUI manager that provides this information for you in the GUI, through an API or via a simple SQL query.

[image: Trigger Misfires View]